# Solr faceting query syntax

Tags: solr

i want to filter faceting counts on a multi valuated field (no docs)

For example:

```
select?q=*:*&rows=5&facet=true&facet.limit=5&facet.field=productID&facet.sort=true
```

is there any chance to filter counts on my facet.field `productId` ?

Given the previous query what i get is:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
−
<lst name="facet_fields">
−
<lst name="productID">
**<int name="EG7SpTw03mJ25vxS5jcB24">603</int>**
<int name="E53OBaX5hjGDAKzbHHaDG1">573</int>
<int name="sSLMrsA0wjLF8iWRAbzNq4">415</int>
<int name="ijcfPOTpg3eeGoXSW8h8L5">336</int>
<int name="Lij0a3kVgQzLxtOMgOXb06">296</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
</lst>
```

I just want to filter the query to get results like:

−
    
    −
    
    603
    573
    415
    336
    296

```
 <lst name="facet_counts">
    <lst name="facet_queries"/>
    −
    <lst name="facet_fields">
    −
    <lst name="productID">
    <int name="E53OBaX5hjGDAKzbHHaDG1">573</int>
    <int name="sSLMrsA0wjLF8iWRAbzNq4">415</int>
    <int name="ijcfPOTpg3eeGoXSW8h8L5">336</int>
    <int name="Lij0a3kVgQzLxtOMgOXb06">296</int>
    <int name="Lij0a3kVgQzLxtOMYERESW">293</int>
    </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="facet_dates"/>
    </lst>
```

Just want to filter by productId:EG7SpTw03mJ25vxS5jcB24 ...

THX

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "filter faceting counts". Please explain with a simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, i found the solution, it's just use the facet.prefix parameter

select?q=*:*&rows=5&facet=true&facet.limit=5&facet.field=productID&facet.sort=true&facet.prefix=EG7SpTw03mJ25vxS5jcB24

The output i get is :

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
−
<lst name="facet_fields">
−
<lst name="taxonUUID">
<int name="EG7SpTw03mJ25vxS5jcB24">603</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
</lst>
```

I'm gonna make a new more complex question about this topic ...